# STM32 enable ADXL345 via SPI

Tags: stm32, spi

I am trying to connect to the ADXL345, which is on another board with GPIOs connected to it (PA5, PA6, PA7, PA12). Also, i am using PulseViewer from [sigrok][1]
The Software shows, that the Sensor is NOT being enabled, yet it seems the functionality is correct. Is there something I'm missing?

```
#include "stm32l0xx.h"
#include "pmi_stddefs.h"

int32_t spi_init_adxl345(void)
{

/* enable SPI1 clock */
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
/* Enable clock for port A */
//RCC->IOPENR |= RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN;
RCC->IOPENR |= RCC_IOPENR_IOPAEN;

/* CPHA at 1, CPOL at 1 */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CPOL;
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CPHA;
/* enable master mode */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;
/* baud rate Maximum (5MHZ ADXL = 011) */
// SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BR_0;
// SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_1;
// SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_2;
SPI1->CR1 |= (SPI_CR1_BR_0)| (SPI_CR1_BR_1);

/* Internal Slave Select */    
/* soft. slave management */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;
/* select slave */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;

/* Frame Format MSB */
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST;
/* Receive only mode enable (0 = full-duplex (Transmit and receive)) */
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_RXONLY;
/* Data frame format 8 */
SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_DFF;

//SPI1->CR2 = SPI_CR2_SSOE | SPI_CR2_RXNEIE;
SPI1->CR2 = 0;


/* Set AF,OUTPUT modes */
/* MISO AF*/
GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE6_0;
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_1;
/* MOSI AF*/
GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7_0;
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE7_1;
/* SCLK AF*/
GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE5_0;
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_1;

// TODO: PUPDR for PA4
// /* CS OUTPUT*/
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE12_0;
GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE12_1;

/* Set I/O output speed (11=very high speed) */
GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEED5;
GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEED6;
GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEED7;
GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEED12;

/* Alternate Function Low Register 9.3.2*/
/* Pin 5,6,7 (in AFRL) */
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5;
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6;
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7;

return RC_SUCC;
}
int32_t spi_txrx (uint8_t *buf, uint32_t size)
{
GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_12;

/* TXE == 1 : the buffer is empty */
while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE))
{
    /* wait untill TXE is empty */
}

for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    SPI1->DR = buf[i];
}

while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE))
{
    /* mandatory wait until TXE is set */
}
/* detect the end of a transfer */
while ((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) != 0)
{
    /* 1:busy, 0:not busy */
}

/* random noise */
uint8_t temp = SPI1->DR;
temp = SPI1->SR;


/* Disable sensor */
GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_12;
/* Diable the SPI <-- No need (Master in full-duplex or transmit 
only mode can finish any transaction when it stops providing data
for transmission. In this case, the clock stops after the last
data transaction.*/
return RC_SUCC;
}
```

Im stuck on this for a reasonable amount of time, yet i didn't find an answer for this issue. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://www.sigrok.org/wiki/PulseView

Comment: How exactly `Sensor is NOT being enabled`? nCS/PA12 stays high/low? BTW, in the `spi_init_adxl345` function PA12 should be set high, since nCS is active low.

Comment: It stays low. I am setting the PA12 high with `GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_12;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SPI nCS lines are typicaly active-low, so PA12 must be set during board startup. In your code ADXL345 is always selected.

This `GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_12;` is reset (`BR` = Bit Reset, `BS` = Bit Set). Also, there is no need to use the `|=` operator, because BSRR is write-only register, designed to change port state without use of the read-modify-write sequence.

2. The `SPE` bit in `SPI_CR1` regisger is not set, SPI is disabled and not transmitting anything. `spi_txrx` would stuck in the second `SPI_SR_TXE` while-loop.
3. Not related to the question, but still - `spi_txrx` looks FIFO-oriened, yet STM32L0-series SPI have only shifter and DR register, and exchange must be implemented on the byte-by-byte basis, or with DMA. Perhaps this code would work for a 1- or 2-byte long transfer, and you'll even get a correct RX result if only last the byte is valuable. But generaly, it's a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are choosing the wrong alternate functions for PA5, PA6 and PA7. Notice that `GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5` is defined as `(0xFUL << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_Pos)`, so when you write it in the `AFR[0]` register you are choosing alternate function 15 (which is not available). However what you want to choose for SPI1 is alternate function 1.

You could try something like

```
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1 << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_Pos);
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1 << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_Pos);
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= (1 << GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_Pos);
```